# /bin/top not found in eshell over ssh

Tags: tramp, shell, eshell

How does eshell resolve its `PATH`?

If I run my `top` in eshell on my local machine, it opens a new buffer and shows the output of the command in it. However, if I do the same on an eshell run on a remote machine I get:

```
/ssh:remote:/home/me/ $ top
----- in *top* bugger -----
..: 1: exec: /ssh:remote:/bin/top: not found

Process /ssh:remote:/bin/top exited abnormally with code 127
```

I certainly do have `top` on the remote machine and it is in `/bin/top`.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in Emacs' master branch, aka Emacs 28.0.50. I recommend you to write a bug report, `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus I did so. Although I use Emacs 27.1, it is kinda stable version. It might well be that I'm just doing something wrong...

Comment: I've seen, thank you. Since I can reproduce the problem, I wouldn't believe that you've done something wrong.

Comment: I can reproduce with a freshly built Emacs from the master branch right now. I started with `emacs -Q`, connected to remote machine, eshell, then top with exactly the same error. It seems to happen with `eshell-visual-commands`, but not with other commands on the remote machine. I get the same error output if I do `M-x term` and then enter the full TRAMP path to `top` on the remote machine.